# Using percentage for height on different resolutions

Tags: html, css

What's a theory behind making divs taking same proportional height on different screen resolutions. For example the following code:

```
<div id="cont1" class="container-fluid">
   <div style="height:91%;overflow-y:auto;">
   </div>
</div>
<div id="cont2" class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:20px;padding:0px;">
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

On a resolution of `1920x1080` `cont2` has more height and as a result its content is closer to the `cont1`. While on `1024x768` that `margin-top` looks better. Why it's not proportionally the same? Also what is a design pattern for that kind of problem?
I am really looking for a generic (at most part at least) solution.

Thanks for help.

Added Fiddle.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0dw4ouoy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On a resolution of 1920x1080 cont2 has more height and as a result its content is closer to the cont1. While on 1024x768 that margin-top looks better. Why it's not proportionally the same?

It might be looking different because both resolutions have different aspect ratio Because `1920/1080 = 1.7777777777777777` and `1024/768 = 1.3333333333333333`. Although `20px` margin-top would look same in both of them.

> Also what is a design pattern for that kind of problem? I am really looking for a generic (at most part at least) solution.

The genric solution is

```
.cont1 > div {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Since `9%` of  different screen heights would be differnt in pixels, that is 9% of 1080px > 9% of 768px. Its better div inside `.cont1` be always same pixels short of its container on screen sizes.

Hope this helps. Cheers !!

Comment: I added Fiddle to my question. I am not sure if the provided style does anything. Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Actually it would work if I use the style as a class instead of an id. But I am facing the same problem as it was before. The 20px has different effect on different resolutions. On 1920X1080 it works perfect, but on 1024x768 it has to be more than 20.

Comment: @Mark I saw your fiddle it looks same on both full hd and medium screen. `20px` would have same effect on all resolutions because it's fixed 20px on all screens. Instead percentage height would have different effect.

Comment: I will try again as soon as I get to my office.